# Removing duplicates in a List<T> based on selection from DataGridView

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0

(Obligatory beginner alert! I can't promise I'll understand everything you tell me.)

I have a program that uses a `List<T>` of a custom class `CheckOrderLine` to populate a `DataGridView` through a `BindingSource`. From within the `dataGrid` control I provide the ability to "split" records into multiple lines for imposition purposes. I'm having trouble working out the reverse of this process.

I need to be able to make a selection in `dataGrid`, get the first selected row to start from, then iterate through each `CheckOrderLine` in the selection and compare them to the first row.

If they all match I need to change the quantity in the first record to be the sum of all the rows selected, then remove the extra rows.

Here's a snippet of what I have worked out on my own so far:

```
        int index = 1;
        while (index < rowToJoin)
        {
            _bs.RaiseListChangedEvents = false;

            int first = _bs.Position;
            int second = first++;
            CheckOrderLine current = (CheckOrderLine)_bs[first];
            CheckOrderLine next = (CheckOrderLine)_bs[second];

            if (current.OrderNumber == next.OrderNumber)
            {
                _bs.RemoveAt(second);
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("You must select at least two matching rows to join.");
                return;
            }

            _bs.RaiseListChangedEvents = true;
            _bs.ResetBindings(false);
            index++;
        }
```

This works only if I select from the bottom up, and only based on the OrderNumber. In order to prevent accidents I really need to check all fields between two rows. Being able to select in any direction would be a bonus at this point.

EDIT: I think I wasn't clear enough originally.

1. I have a method that can split a row into 2-5 new rows.
2. My original code can join any number of rows, but only if selected bottom to top, and based on `OrderNumber`.
3. Is there a more efficient way to compare two rows other than `current.OrderNumber == next.OrderNumber`? I know I could add all my fields into the `if` statement, but i'd prefer to have it more reusable.
4. Selecting in any direction is a distant second to comparing between all fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it only works when you select from bottom-up is that `BindingSource.Current` points to the last item that was selected, so if you select from top-down, you're comparing with unselected items.

You also seem to have a mistake which is causing your `first` and `second` to be reversed. You're using a postfix increment operation when you probably didn't mean to.

Let's say `_bs.Position` is 5;

```
int first = _bs.Position;  // first is now 5
int second = first++;  // postfix increment: second is now 5, first is now 6
```

As the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36x43w8w.aspx) says,

> the result of the operation is the value of the operand before it has
>   been incremented

So you've really done this:

```
second = first;
first = first + 1;
```

It looks like you just wanted to do this:

```
second = first + 1;
```

It probably made no difference in this case but it makes for pretty confusing code.

---

There are numerous approaches to what you are trying to do. Here is perhaps a more direct and understandable way:

```
int count = dgv.SelectedRows.Count;

// DataGridView.SelectedRows is reverse order, so the first selected item is the last item in the list
var firstSelected = dgv.SelectedRows[count - 1].DataBoundItem as CheckOrderLine;
int firstOrderNumber = firstSelected.OrderNumber;

// starting at second-last item (second selected row)
for (int i = count - 2; i >= 0; i--)
{
    var row = dgv.SelectedRows[i];
    var item = row.DataBoundItem as CheckOrderLine;
    if (item.OrderNumber == firstOrderNumber)
        dgv.Rows.Remove(row);
}
```

To keep it simple I've left out updating the remaining row, and any error checking.

Note that this will work even if the matching rows aren't consecutive. It's up to you to allow that or not.

Comment: I knew why it only worked when I selected it a certain way. The error in making `first` and `second` were completely unknown to me. I'll give this a go tomorrow morning and see how it goes. Thank you.

Comment: I just gave this a go and it solves the direction issue perfectly, but it only works for 2 records at a time.

Comment: That can't be right... there's nothing in this code that will limit it to two rows. What's your  gridview's SelectionMode? Set it to FullRowSelect or RowHeaderSelect.

Comment: It's set to full row select. It looks like if I have anything more than 2 selected it will only remove 2 at a time.

Comment: I just tested this and it's working for any number of items, and will always keep the first item selected while deleting any other items that match it. I'm having trouble guessing why it's working differently for you.

Comment: HAH! Got it. I stupidly put this into my `while` block rather than replacing it. It's amazing how a little sleep can help me see better. Thanks for your help.